# Sqldeveloper El trabajo se ha cancelado y la importación se ha revertido. Tarea cancelada

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

> Import Data to the STUDENT Table of the C: \ Users \ .... \
>   STUDENT.xlsx File. The job has been cancelled and the import has been
>   rolled back. Task Cancelled.

La tabla STUDENTS fue creada asi

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
(
    ID_LECTOR VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO VARCHAR2(50),
    GENERO_A CHAR(1),
    DIRECCION NVARCHAR2(100),
    CORREO NVARCHAR2(50)
);

ALTER TABLE ESTUDIANTE 
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ESTUDIANTE PRIMARY KEY(ID_LECTOR);
```

y el excel tiene 50000 registros de este estilo

```
18994951-9  Niobe   Guardado    m   96 Plaza de Espaaa  49977Ezilda.Alicea894@doit.com
```

Ayuda por favor, ocurre solo con la tabla ESTUDIANTE, creo que es porque son demasiados datos porque la probe con 30000 y funcionó pero lo raro es que he cargado otras tablas con 50000 y no he tenido problemas.

Comment: Muestra la consulta SQL. Por otro lado, el error marca que la tabla se llama STUDENT pero la has creado como STUDENTS y depués indicas que se llama ESTUDIANTE?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y traduce las dos lineas que tienes en inglés. Tambien te recomiendo que pases por [ask] y realices el [tour] para asi poder ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: @Flowen eso no importa, está bien en realidad es solopara mostrar el hecho del error que surge..